# How to search column for empty string using Sequelize.js?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a variable called `data.val`. And a query to check if the value is inside my table. But it doesn't work if the variable is an empty string `data.val=''`.

How can I search for empty string in Sequelize.js????

My Sequelize query is:

```
models.table_data.findOne({
            where:{
                id_person:data.id_person,
                id_agr_data:data.id_agr_data,
                id_tram:data.id_tram,
                value:data.val
            }
        }).then(data_person=>{
            if(data_person){
                resolve(true);
            }else{
                resolve(false);         
            }
        }).catch(err=>{
            reject("ERROR");
        });
```

The problem is in `value:data.val`. When I have, for example a value **'A'** in my table and `data.val='A'` it works. But when the variable is equal to empty string is like it doesn't search for the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I think the default value of `value` field in `table` must be `null` and not `empty string`

So you can change the query like :

```
value: data.val != '' ? data.val : null
// OR
Set the `value`'s default value empty string
```

Comment: In the database design the field can have empty string, It can't have `NULL`. But if I could change it to `NULL` instead of empty string, the question remains. How to query an empty string in Sequelize.js